# Design for inheritance and reuse of visual elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, windows-runtime, winjs

I know with C++/C#, you can create controls that are reusable piece of code that you can use through inheritance etc. However, I am not sure if same principles could be used in a Windows 8 store app build using CSS, JavaScript and HTML5. If its possible, can you please pin-point what are the key elements from each technology (CSS, JavaScript/WinJS, HTML5) that can help designing your windows 8 app for inheritance and reuse of visual elements.

TIA

Comment: jQuery widgets (aka plugins) and DurandalJS views/widgets are two examples of "reusable components". Inheritance (of types) is only one method for code-reuse and is completely orthogonal to UI and UI composition. I'm sure there are some *specific approaches for Windows 8 applications* (which I do not develop for) to leverage the runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are few things I have come across for code reuse, in javascript based windows store application.

1. custom controls - There are times when we need to build a custom control that can be reused across pages, and sometimes in multiple projects. [This link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/10/11/building-a-custom-control-using-the-windows-library-for-javascript-winjs.aspx) gives overview of building custom control using WinJS lib. For example - I have built one custom control to ImageSelectControl. Many times we need a control to display the selected image, allow user to change/delete the selected image, display a thumbnail of the selected image in the control etc. I use this control across multiple pages in an app.
2. default.css - this contains the default styling for the project. Over building couple of apps, I have come across set of default css classes, styles that are added on top of the default generated by the vs template. I copy this file across projects. for example - every app has a 'branding' color scheme. based on that, you need to set the anchor hover color, input select control background etc. such rules are reusable across project and only the branding color changes. it is good to identify and organize such rules in your default.css and reuse it across projects.
3. default.js - this file also goes through some updates for app life-cycle event handling. if you keep the data model separation for the project, this file can be re-used across project.
4. [WinJS.Class.derive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229815.aspx) func is available to define inheritance. but so far, I have not come across significant usage of this in my projects.
5. you will come across your personal templates (set of .html/css/js files) for different kind of pages. it is good to reuse them. I have created few of them (not all such templates) but I plan to create them. as you work across multiple of your apps, good to look out for such templates and start your page development from one of your templates. templates can be simply maintained as a folder say template\ with the set of .html/.js/.css file and copy paste these files into your new page folder.
6. Utilility libs - you will build your set of utils helper functions. I keep them in js/utils.js and share across projects. For example - Utils.handleError(error): display message in case of error to the user; Utils.UI.initializeWithProgressRing that loads the page with a promise and displays progress ring at the center until the page is loaded; your Wrappers for WinJS.xhr. good to check WinJS.Utilities namespace before building your helper function. I have found some times the required function here.

in summary - code reuse happens in my case, at reusing js utility libs, templates for pages, default.js, default.css, custom controls. inheritance is available but i have not used as much. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

So for HTML and JavaScript Windows 8 applications there are definitely ways to achieve the same amount of code reusability and in fact most of the patterns use the same nomenclature, so if you google for "winjs" plus whatever you're looking for, you'll find great examples most of the time.

Per your specific question:

- CSS classes referenced in the default.html page of a [navigation application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452768.aspx#navigation_models__multi-page_and_single-page) can be utilized throughout the application. (Actually any style that is loaded is retained in memory so if you visit a detail page and it has a style for headers that is not specific to the actual page, it may apply to another page's detail page after it is first loaded.)
- HTML pages can be referenced in page controls and iframes so you can reuse those layouts in multiple places just as you would a normal website.
- JavaScript, as it applies to Windows 8 applications, is actually very well fleshed out. There is a great set of utilities for code organization built-in to the environment for [namespacing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967793.aspx), [defining and deriving classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967790.aspx), all allowing for easy [creation of controls](http://www.gotdibbs.net/blog/2012/11/11/a-skeleton-for-custom-controls-with-winjs/), etc.

This is of course not to mention other peoples' comments about pre-existing HTML/CSS/JavaScript techniques being available for use on the platform. Have a favorite JQuery plugin? Chances are it still works in Windows 8.

Answer (score -1):

SASS provides excellent tools for including and re-using CSS styles: http://sass-lang.com/

As for HTML and JS, you could use PHP to store code snippets in variables and arrays. As well, the same logic applies with re-producing HTML elements in JS... just store markup or snippets in variables: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp

Does this help?

Comment: Well I am building app for Windows 8. That's why I have used tags like WinJS and Windows Runtime. Not sure if you answer applies to this context?

Comment: Please avoid linking to w3schools if possible - there are many better resources, even if w3schools still gets top google responses.

Comment: @JodyHeavener Search for "w3fools"; it is a very subpar informational site compared to alternatives ..

Comment: PHP doesn't run inside of Windows 8 applications. They are strictly HTML/JS/CSS and/or XAML/C# for the most part. The only way PHP could come into play would be if you're making web service calls from your app.